# How can I get the lang inside my controller in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I am sending a post request to a controller with axios. The languge is set to `fr` and all blade texts are also changed to `fr` but if I send a post request using axios it doesn't translate from the controller. I tried to see the language in the controller and it always shows `en`.

Here is the code I am using..

Initial route to load the login blade

```
Route::get('/{lang?}/login', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
```

This route inside a middleware which set the lang according to the lang variable.

Post request using axios

```
Route::post('user/login', [
   'uses' => 'loginController@login'
 ]);
```

Inside `loginController@login`

```
$loc=config('app.locale');
\Log::info($loc); // It always shows en
```

And I am trying to return the translated text like this

```
return response()->json([
      'error' => trans('Invalid Details') // I am using string as key in fr.json file
 ],401);
```

**I think trans function is not working for me not even in my blade where in blade @lang('key') and {{__(key')}} work just fine but not the trans function
**

Do I have to set the locale in every routes whether it is an ajax request or plain get request? Because I set the locale when the page was loaded initially so do I have to do it again for ajax requests too?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to set local inside your controller,

```
function showLoginForm($language){
    app()->setLocale($language);
    ........
    ........
}
```

If you want to set local for all sub route, then try following one

```
// set locale for '/admin/anything/[en|fr|ru|jp]/anything' only
if (in_array(Request::segment(1),['en', 'fr', 'ru', 'jp'])) {
    App::setLocale(Request::segment(1));
} else {
    // set default / fallback locale
    App::setLocale('en');
}

Route::group(['prefix' => '{locale}'], function() {
    Route::resource('product', 'ProductController', ['except' => [
    'show'
    ]]);
});
```

Comment: well, I tried to hard set the local and then tried to translate. It set the local but didn't translate. 
` $loc=config('app.locale');
        \Log::info($loc);`
trans('Invalid Details')

It didn't work either though I hard coded the local before calling the trans function

Comment: `config('app.locale')` will only receive the current local language code. To set language please use `app()->setLocale('fr)`

Comment: Sorry I did like this ` \App::setLocale('fr');` And it set correctly

Comment: Nope, it set the locale to fr but trans function always returns key not the translation from `fr.json` file inside lang folder

Comment: The language file should locate like this `/resources/lang/fr/validation.php`. Please refer [link]https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/localization

Comment: Nope, see this I am using like this and it is working in all of my blade and even in my .vue files but not in controller

https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/localization#using-translation-strings-as-keys

Comment: well, I see the trans function don't even work on blade. @lang('key) r {{__('key')}} Works in blade

Comment: Great. It worked like this 
`return response()->json([
                'error' => __('Login Successful')

            ],401);`

Comment: Try `__('Invalid Details')` in blade file

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/156153/discussion-between-praveen-tamil-and-sadek).

Comment: Main question is why the post request cannot get the locale which was set to fr when I first loaded the page using the middleware ?